# removeCachedResponseForRequest not work in iOS 9.3.1

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview

Does removeCachedResponseForRequest work. I am trying to clear cache of uiwebview.
Any alternative of removeCachedResponseForRequest except removeAllCachedResponses that can be used to achieve clearing cache of a webview.